# React Three Fiber Primitive doesn't wrap texture using map prop

Tags: react-three-fiber

[Hi, I am trying to add texture to 3d modal loaded through useLoader i use primitive that react three fiber provides and when i add map prop and pass img to it, it doesn't work. please help me][1]

````
import { useLoader, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader'
import { Environment, OrbitControls, OrthographicCamera } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useState, Suspense } from "react";
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
import { Texture, TextureLoader } from "three";
import Wrapper from "../assets/wrapper.jpg";



const Scene = () => {

    const ref = useRef();

    useFrame(() => {
        // ref.current.rotation.z += 0;
        ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
        // ref.current.rotation.x = 0.09;
        // ref.current.rotation.x += -170;
    });
    const img = useLoader(TextureLoader, Wrapper);
    const obj = useLoader(OBJLoader, 'fibbia_wrap.obj');

    return (
        <>
          <primitive map={img} ref={ref} object={obj} scale={0.6} />
        </>
    )
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KixV1.png
````

Answer (score 0):

In this case, don't use primitive.

**1**) First, export your modal in.glb form.
**2**) Then use gltfjsx package, this package will auto-generate JSX code for your modal.
Which then you can use. In order to learn more about this package go to (https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx).
**3**) After that you are good to go the gltfjsx package provides code consisting of mesh and mesh can take map property which primitive can't.